# Single page application bug in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Update:** The new release of 201202 update fixed it.

I tried the following,

1. Create a new SPA project (Asp.Net MVC 4.0 2012.2 Update)
2. Upgrade all the references using NuGet.
3. Run the web application. Create a test account for the default "Todo" application and logged.

On the right top, the page shows "Hello, test | Log off". However, the two links don't response mouse hovering in Chrome and Firefox. Actually the Log off works when you move the mouse cursor to "ff" of the word "off".

Is there any quick fix? How to report Microsoft for the bug?

**Update:**

I found that remove the following style will make the two links work.

```
#userSettings {
float: right;
}

<div id="userSettings">

    Hello, <a class="username" href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">test</a>
<form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xKY5UfTGZG8gx3NVn6fHLGcV_LgdR9Hyk0dqxJm3GzHY02_WXxHoxDI00RdvWQagTvthHaH6vcuDTN-Fu_us7T2V08fJXyoePjOmLOZzX3M1">       
  <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
</form>    

</div>
<div id="body">...</div>
```

The computed Style of < Div id="userSettings">

```
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
float: right;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 19px;
height: 25px;
width: 157px;
```

The computed style of < div id="body>

```
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 19px;
height: 476.71875px;
width: 980px;
```

It seems that the div "body" covered div "userSettings". However, not sure why the mouse cursor changes after it hovers on "ff" of "logoff".

Comment: `How to report Microsoft for the bug?` - on http://connect.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking a wild guess, but that sounds like a boxmodel issue, possibly resolved with a clearfix.